# CLLocation data getting null in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager, clgeocoder

Hello I am getting user location using `CLLocationManager`I can get latitude,longitude,country name and administrative area. But I want to get the city name or sub administrative area.

```
NSString *address = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@\n%@ %@\n%@\n%@",
                             self.placemark.subThoroughfare, self.placemark.thoroughfare,
                             self.placemark.postalCode, self.placemark.subLocality,
                             self.placemark.subAdministrativeArea,
                            self. placemark.country];
```

but except the country andthoroughfare other values are null. Why is that? How can I solve this issue? Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: get country and address info from addressdictionary

Answer (score 0):

you have to get country value and address string from `addressDictionary` Like

```
NSDictionary *dictAddress = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:placemark.addressDictionary];
    NSMutableDictionary *dictTxtData = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    NSLog(@"country:%@",dictAddress[@"Country"]);
```

you have to get other details from `placemark`

```
NSLog(@"thoroughfare:%@",placemark.thoroughfare);
    NSLog(@"subThoroughfare:%@",placemark.subThoroughfare);
    NSLog(@"subAdministrativeArea:%@",placemark.subAdministrativeArea);
    NSLog(@"postCode:%@",placemark.postalCode);
```

if you have get nil value then change location or check with popular location and check it again and use direct `placemark` insten of `self.placemark`.
my output is:
[image]

Comment: but this has only country code,country,state and street,, how can I get the city name or sub administrative area?

Comment: @user1960169 please check my updated ans . in my case i have used placemark without self and  please check with set popular location. many times location manager not get location properly.